# JS Room Monthly Challenge December

Tags: discussion, chat

Thanks for voting! The selected challenge is:

> **Go**
>
> **Task:** Write a program that gets a chat room ID and fetches the number of stars for each user in the chat and then returns a sorted list of users by number of stars.

You can start working on it today - more information will follow soon.

You *may* submit your code to [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/JavaScriptRoom/JS-Monthly-Challenge-Dec-14) but is is not required in order to participate.

---

We at [the JS chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) want to throw short monthly challenges where everyone gets the same task in a new language/library/framework. After [the last one was successful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276688/js-room-monthly-challenge-voting) we're looking at a new challenge for December.

The idea is to learn a new technology, code something fun and share knowledge, opinions and experience. The scope is meant to be rather small. It's something one should be able to hack together in an evening of work.

**Post your ideas here. Once an idea is chosen, post your solutions in the JavaScript chat room, or hang out there and examine others' solutions.**

#### Format:

> Language/Framework/Library
>
> Task: Description here

Please try to suggest something new that it is unlikely room members already did:

Here's an example:

> **Scala**
>
> **Task:** Write a parser in scala that accepts a `.json` file and reads all the numbers in the file. The output is a JSON file containing all the numeric values in an array. You may not use any existing JSON parsers.

As you can see - it uses a non-JS technology (Scala) has a clear and small goal and is doable.

Voting and submitting ideas will start today and end in 5 days.

You may vote even if you're not going to participate. If you're not a room regular in the [JS chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) you're welcome to join us in the challenge.

Good luck.

Comment: FWIW: I support using meta to coordinate this sort of thing because it reduces the isolation otherwise inherent in chat: folks can learn the rules for participation without having to have spent the past *n* months lurking in the room. For better or worse, chat *is* a part of Stack Overflow - therefore, questions regarding the rules and traditions of chat are nominally on-topic here. Also, I cleared a bunch of mostly-irrelevant comments here; if you're interested, see Félix's chat link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66066/discussion-between-felix-gagnon-grenier-and-tmyklebu).

Comment: @Shog9: You support using meta for this only because there's no other place to put it that isn't chat?

Comment: No. If you want a longer explanation than what's in the comment above, ask a separate question @tmyklebu.

Comment: @Kendra I feel dumb, I didn't fully read Shog's comment.  Felix's chat link explains it well enough, I do agree the comments were kind of getting out of hand.  I'll remove my comment, derp.

Comment: Is this a http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ topic collection or something ?

Comment: I followed the right sidebar link here, to be somewhat surprised that JS Room's monthly challenge is neither monthly nor in JavaScript. That is, of course, fine: thank you for organizing it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Go**

**Task:** Write a program that gets a chat room ID and fetches the number of stars for each user in the chat and then returns a sorted list of users by number of stars.

Comment: Related: A while ago I did this in Python and put the code up for review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48258/well-be-counting-stars

Answer (score 34):

**Erlang / Elixir**

**Task**: Write a simple calculator (Polish notation, infix, reverse-screw Hungarian, whichever you'd like). Should implement at least addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulo and power. If the result is an integer, query [Numbers API](http://numbersapi.com/#42) for some interesting trivia (being interesting optional).

(Note: You can assume nicely given input, so don't stress too much on parsing. e.g. `10 * 8` and not `10*8`)

*Edit:*

Erlang references:

- Nice intro: http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/erlang/
- Amazing book (a particular chapter may spoil this challenge, though!): http://learnyousomeerlang.com/
- Erlang docs: http://www.erlang.org/doc.html

General help on creating a calculator:

- [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)
- [Reverse-Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)

  - Some random implementations of RPN in ML, Haskell and Ruby: https://gist.github.com/jbpotonnier/3976975
- For good ol' infix, there's the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

  - Here's my terrible and old (and terribly old) implementation: https://gist.github.com/Zirak/6341918

Comment: I gotta tell ya, being a hungarian, I'm quite offended by "reverse-screw Hungarian".... nah, just kidding! name it however you like it :)

Comment: No offense but the I would like to learn anything but Erlang at this time. I have never seen an add whereby Erlang/Elixir was up on the job market. It seems a time-waste in a practical sense.

Comment: @samaYo While the market for Brainfuck, LOLCODE and Shakespear programmers is in a constant inflation!
It's not about learning something practical, the challenge is to challenge you to learn something new and different. Practicality optional.

Answer (score 26):

**Dart**

**Task:** Create an interface for suggesting and voting on monthly challenge ideas.  I originally said this on the chat as a joke, but it seems within the difficulty target, and would let us avoid opening Meta questions each month that routinely get put on hold.

Front-end only, with a mock REST API for the backend.  (Actual backend would be need to be implemented separately... or perhaps next month?)

---

(I'm open to other languages than Dart if we want this task but not the language; it's just something that's been on my list of things to try for awhile)

---

EDIT: please only upvote this if you think it would actually be a good programming challenge; not simply because you don't want this thread here.

Comment: I think this is kind of abusive since it'll get upvotes from people who don't like the thread here.

Comment: I mean, we could always just ask people *not* to upvote this just because they don't like this thread here.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum wouldn't it be in fact the best challenge that could be accepted this month? People genuinely interested in this being repeated over the months will have an interface to push the concept further, and people not wanting this here will not see it here :). there's a drawback: probably less people would see that interface compared to having a question on meta per month...

Answer (score 19):

**Brainfuck**

**Task:** Write a program that chooses a random number from 1 to 100. The user then attempts to guess this number. After each guess the program tells the user if his/her guess was bigger or smaller than the correct number, or correct. Finally, the program should tell the user how many guesses he/she took.

---

**Random number generation**

Since brainfuck doesn't have good ways of seeding the random number generator, it's enough that the numbers are seemingly random the first time the program is run - that is, it's okay to generate the same numbers on the second run. The numbers may not, however, be hardcoded. They must be generated in a way that a (normal) human cannot predict the generated numbers.

A valid way of seeding the random numbers, and I actually recommend doing this as a potential bonus task, is asking the user for a random seed. The user may then proceed to faceroll his/her keyboard, and the program uses the input as the random number generator's seed.

---

A very simple program, however I think brainfuck in itself will f**ck your brain. Learning the language is the easiest task imaginable, but looking at it and understanding the code is very intimidating.

Comment: This sounds fun

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum we'll see :D

Comment: What's wrong with good old fizzbuzz? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57382/fizzbuzz-in-brainfuck

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Sure, that works too. Well not now really since you linked an implementation...

Comment: For the record: I have been tempted at making a high/low guessing game as well. Just haven't done that yet.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg And now you have an excuse!

Comment: Better yet, change the number after each guess.

Comment: @Robbert now that's just mean

Comment: @Robbert, that's pure evil, I like it.

Comment: And who did _not_ write this program when they learned programming? I remember my algorithm teacher having us write this program before he explained to us what binary search was.

Comment: Good luck generating random numbers in a language without random number generator (as deterministic as it gets).

Comment: @xfix You do realize most languages simply have libraries that support pseudo-random number generation? With brainfuck you just have to code it yourself. This was the first thing I found googling: [link](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms#x_.3D_pseudo-random_number)

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja: You would need to seed the initial seed somehow, which is pretty much impossible, however. If you read the example, you will notice you need to define seed. You cannot use random number generator for generating seed, because it wasn't seeded. Using the same seed will make the random number generator generate the same numbers.

Comment: @xfix so what's the issue? I didn't say the numbers can't be the same, only that they should be seemingly random

Comment: @xfix actually I didn't... Anyway a pseudorandom number is enough.

Comment: Edited the task description.

Comment: Any character not "><+-.,[]" (excluding quotation marks) is ignored. WOW!!

Comment: The code in @CaryBondoc's comment above prints *nothing*, takes user input and then enters an infinite loop.

Answer (score 14):

**R**

Plot out when [the plot thickened](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=the%20plot%20thickens&sort=newest) given a vector of dates (or timestamps). Also plot out a histogram (or whatever) of how many times different people recognised the differing thickness.

Bonus "points" for fetching and parsing the data yourself.

(If you're interested: [very quick intro to R](http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/r/) ; [an awesome book on R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387954759) (you may be able to find it online *cough cough*) ; for most everything else, `?funcName` in the R repl)

Comment: "you may be able to find it online *cough cough*" Are suggesting that people should violate Mr. Dalgaard's/Springer's copyright and obtain that book without paying for it?

Comment: More like - it's also available in ebook format http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-79053-4

Comment: Man you should get that cold checked out, Zirak, sounds bad.

Comment: Can you please explain what *the plot thickened* means? It looks like a meme or a private joke from this chatroom.

Comment: @A.L A combination of [this quote](http://www.xkcdb.com/602) with [this comic](http://xkcd.com/1022/). It somewhen became a gag of sorts (by...erm...someone *cough cough*)

Answer (score 9):

**Bash**

Task:  Write a engine can translate text in markdown format to html. Can translate **bold**, *italic* and `code` tags.

Comment: Sorry, but I already know Javascript so I'm downvoting this.

Comment: Sorry benjamin-gruenbaum. I read "JS Room ...." title and think that using js to do some task.

So now I change my suggest from Javascript to Bash. I saw my teacher using bash to solve "Ping-pong" kata. So how if we using bash to solve my old suggest?

Comment: Upvoted - this sounds more interesting.

Answer (score 4):

[**Famo.us**](http://famo.us)

Implement Pong using the Famo.us API only (that is, no HTML in the body).
I know this is JavaScript, but AFAIK Famo.us is a new technology, as such matching the requirements.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine challenge. It's ok to have a JS challenge that uses a new library.

Answer (score 1):

**XQuery**

**Task**: Read in the [factbook.xml](http://www.w3.org/XML/Binary/2005/03/test-data/Over100K/factbook.xml) and display for each country in the world the population of this country and the difference in the number of inhabitants compared to all its neighboring countries. Based on the estimated population growth (and the assumption this number is steady for the next ten years), also return how much the difference will grow/shrink.

---

For all JS folks out there as a reminder that there still is XML in this world and although it is not as cool as Json, it can do very nice things. XQuery is a functional language intended for processing XML. I would restrict this to XQuery 3.0 (the most current spec), which has nice higher order functions and lots of functional features. Popular Implementations are [eXist](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/homepage/index.html) or [BaseX](http://basex.org) (full disclosure: I am a member of BaseX).

Answer (score 1):

**[Shakespeare](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/)**

**Task**: Write a program to calculate the factors of an arbitrary number and display them in a sorted list.  Goals should be readability and brevity of the source (which will resemble an amateurish play).

While Shakespeare isn't truly a *practical* language, it does force the programmer to deal with more esoteric concepts and understand what is actually driving the code to work, as opposed to learning the ins-and-outs of a framework.

Comment: Wow, did not know SPL existed. I want to try it, but trying to run the `makefile` results in errors for me. Does it compile for you?

Comment: Mindblowing.  I could spend a lot of time playing with that.

Comment: @SomeGuy Compiled fine for me, but I already had all the compiler's dependencies.  You might want to check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050362/translating-shakespeare-programming-language

Comment: I do have the dependencies. Seem to get errors about undefined references to 'yylineno' in grammar.tab.c

Comment: @SomeGuy Sounds like you're running into an issue with your Flex dependency, as `yylineno` is a module within Flex.  I'd give it a go reinstalling to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I reinstalled but it didn't work. It did after I ran `make clean` in the root directory, though. There are still problems with the translated code, sadly :/

Answer (score -1):

Since it's last month's ex aequo answer:

**Ada**

**Task:** Write an IRC client. It can be a simple bot answering `!!bot` with `Yes, I'm a bot!`. It does mean implementing the IRC protocol. A simple way to understand how it works is using [irc over telnet](http://www.ucc.asn.au/~matt/mirror/irctelnet.html).

Answer (score -5):

**[LOLCODE](http://lolcode.org/language.html)**

Write a short **[POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) Client** that fetches the last mail available on the Server and stores it into a local file. The Client doesn't need to support any encryption, plain text connections are enough (feel free to support it anyway).

Answer (score -11):

**CraftyJS**

**Task** : Use crafty.js in conjugation WebkitSpeechRecognition api to copy a simple SIMON so you basically speak :P as you press too fun for kids. (So basically you speak what you want your card to perform)).

Comment: WebkitSpeechRecognition might make an interesting challenge, crafty.js might make an interesting challenge, but both together is too much I think.  (And the problem itself sounds beyond the "single night of work" criteria)

Comment: @Retsam its pretty single night of work. WebkitSpeechRecognition is pretty straightforward, it **is** an event stream, talking about the rest of it meh I'd probably be able to do it in single night or maybe 2 but oki ^_^ i get what you are sayin :-)

Comment: What if i reduce the challenge from crafty pokemon to just SIMON ?

Comment: So your challenge idea is what? Designing a card game or using WebkitSpeechRecognition? I don't think it is an appropriate challenge the way it is presented at this moment. Something simple like Simon makes more sense to me because the point of this challenge is not to invent a card game but to use new technologies. So the challenge should be a well defined idea to be implemented and not so much a general thought to be expanded on.