# JS Room Monthly Challenge January

Tags: discussion, chat

Thanks for voting! The selected challenge is:

> **RxJS and React**
>
> **Task:** Use RxJS and react to implement any game based on the subject of gravity - that is the player is affected by gravity somehow. The game can be as simple (like jump every 5 seconds) or as hard as you'd like (like flappy bird a or more).

You can start working on it today.

You *may* submit your code to [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/JavaScriptRoom/JS-Monthly-Challenge-Jan-15) but is is not required in order to participate.

---

We at [the JS chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) want to throw short monthly challenges where everyone gets the same task in a new language/library/framework. After [the last one was successful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278142/js-room-monthly-challenge-december) we're looking at a new challenge for January.

The idea is to learn a new technology, code something fun and share knowledge, opinions and experience. The scope is meant to be rather small. It's something one should be able to hack together in an evening of work.

**Post your ideas here. Once an idea is chosen, post your solutions in the JavaScript chat room, or hang out there and examine others' solutions.**

#### Format:

> Language/Framework/Library
>
> Task: Description here

Please try to suggest something new that it is unlikely room members already did:

Here's an example:

> **Scala**
>
> **Task:** Write a parser in scala that accepts a `.json` file and reads all the numbers in the file. The output is a JSON file containing all the numeric values in an array. You may not use any existing JSON parsers.

As you can see - it uses a non-JS technology (Scala) has a clear and small goal and is doable.

Voting and submitting ideas will start today and end in 5 days.

You may vote even if you're not going to participate. If you're not a room regular in the [JS chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) you're welcome to join us in the challenge.

Good luck.

Comment: Isn't this a question for CodeGolf.SE?

Comment: @ThomasW. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278142/js-room-monthly-challenge-december#comment123597_278142

Comment: The link to the GitHub repo points to the repo for December's challenge. The January 2015 repo is located at [https://github.com/JavaScriptRoom/JS-Monthly-Challenge-Jan-15](https://github.com/JavaScriptRoom/JS-Monthly-Challenge-Jan-15)

Comment: @dennisschagt oops! thanks :)

Answer (score 12):

**RxJS and React**

**Task** : Use RxJS and react to implement any game based on the subject of gravity - that is the player is affected by gravity somehow. The game can be as simple (like jump every 5 seconds) or as hard as you'd like (like flappy bird a or more).

Answer (score 12):

**Io**

**Task**: Write a [Pokédex](http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/all). Given a Pokémon id, write out its stats (type, hp, attack, speed, etc). Also accept a range (6-12), or display "pages" (e.g. given #1, display Pokémon 1-10, #2 11-20, etc).

Data source can be prepared beforehand or bonus points for fetching it on the fly.

Language references:

- Official website http://iolanguage.org/
- Official guide http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html
- Wikibooks entry: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Io_Programming
- Two small introductory articles: http://ozone.wordpress.com/2006/03/15/blame-it-on-io/ and http://ozone.wordpress.com/2006/03/20/little-manual-of-cloning-for-io-programmers/
- If you're really hardcore, implementation: https://github.com/stevedekorte/io

Comment: An actual Pokedex is a nightmare, btw. Good choice on just the name, ID, and stats. That makes it much, much simpler, faster, and easy to pull in/lookup and build.

Comment: What's Io? I guess it's not io.js, the recent fork of node...

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Added language references

Answer (score 8):

**Markov Chains**

**Task** : Create a parser that pulls headlines from [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/news) and generates new ones via Markov Chains.  Headlines can be retrieved from [the Firebase API](http://blog.ycombinator.com/hacker-news-api)

Language/Framework agnostic.  I figured this was something a lot of developers keep meaning to get around to learning.

Comment: What language/framework/library is this task in?

Answer (score 7):

**Clojure**

**Task**: Write a web crawler which collects all links in a given url, follows them and builds a hierarchy of links. Specify a max depth, of course.

For example, crawling [Clojure's github page](https://github.com/clojure/clojure) and a depth=2 would give something like this:

- https://github.com/clojure/clojure

  - http://clojure.org/

    - http://help.wikispaces.com/
    - http://clojure.org/
    - http://clojure.org/home
    - http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Home
    - irc://irc.freenode.net/#clojure
    - ...
  - http://opensource.org/licenses/eclipse-1.0.php

    - http://opensource.org/
    - http://opensource.org/about
    - http://opensource.org/osd
    - http://opensource.org/licenses
    - http://opensource.org/working_groups
    - http://opensource.org/faq
    - http://opensource.org/trademark
    - http://opensource.org/osr-intro
    - ...
  - ...

Bonus points for:

- Not visiting the same url twice
- Respecting [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)
- Respecting nofollow
- Drawing a graph.
- Being awesome

Answer (score 3):

**Object Pascal (Delphi / Free Pascal, Lazarus)**

**Task:** Write an HTTP proxy that will replace all images on websites with cat images (images with the `cat` tag) from Flickr.

Comment: @Unihedro right, sorry for not specifying that clearly. Of course the ones with `cat` tag.

Answer (score 2):

**Prolog**

**Task**: Write a solver for verbal arithmetic puzzles in Prolog.  For example,

```
 SEND
+MORE
 =====
 MONEY
```

should yield O = 0, M = 1, Y = 2, E = 5, N = 6, D = 7, R = 8, and S = 9.

Answer (score -4):

**Ruby**

**Task**: Write an http exploration tool. Input is something like this:

```
GET http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797
```

Output:

```
{
    "main": {
        "temp": 299.552,
        "temp_min": 299.552,
        "temp_max": 299.552,
        "pressure": 1004.77,
        "sea_level": 1022.43,
        "grnd_level": 1004.77,
        "humidity": 100
    },
    "dt": 1420224172,
    "id": 2172797,
    "name": "Cairns",
    "cod": 200,
    [...snip...]
}
```

But just that is boring! Allow specifying headers:

```
GET http://httpbin.org/headers
User-Agent: FoobarInc
```

Output:

```
{
  "user-agent": "FoobarInc"
}
```

And of course, support different verbs and giving in input (simply separate body from headers with a newline):

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/Ralt/pastie/issues
Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "title": "You're pretty",
    "body": "Hi handsome"
}
```

How the response status/headers is shown is up to you.

Bonus points for

- Handling redirects
- Supporting comments inside/around queries.
- Pretty-printing json/xml/whatever results.
- Massive props for supporting variables (syntax up to you)

Answer (score -9):

**Common Lisp**

**Task**: create a website to let my couple decide how much money each of us puts in the common account. On a prorata of our salaries, each of us puts in a total amount of money to let us pay the bills. Basically, a form with 2 inputs (my salary, SO's salary), and the 3rd input being how much money we need for the month/week.